# First appearance of a normal distribution table in a publication

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, normal-distribution, math-history

The French Wikipedia article *[History of the normal distribution](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_loi_normale#Les_tables_num%C3%A9riques)* is quite precise on that question (translation mine):

> The first table ever made was by Laplace in 1778 who was using the
> normal distribution as an approximation to the hypergeometric
> distribution, and that table got published in 1781.

Does anyone know where to find a scanned version of that table, or any other kind of support for this fact (other than the given reference book by Yadolah Dodge which cannot seem to be found online)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/27643700

Comment: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/stahl96.pdf

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much, that's interesting - it contradicts the article that I was mentioning. It would be interesting to have access to these old papers to know who's right.